# Corousel not working properly showing flex form

Tags: javascript, html, css

My CSS looks like this, for `.mySlides`. I tried every display still its not working.

[image: this is how it looks]

I have not made use of w3-animate style idk how to use that.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
showSlides();
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: flex;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  position: cover;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.dot {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.active {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
}

span {
  color: black;
  /* background-color: white; */
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-right">
    <img src="https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,w_980,c_limit,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0/assets/images/2021/12/7/53ae79ec-df56-4877-b133-b92f4cfd8c7f1638892785287-EORS-Prebuzz-Banner-DK.gif" style="width: 100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-right">
    <img src="https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,w_980,c_limit,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0/assets/images/2021/12/11/073805e4-f274-4d37-b5e3-8ef4766a19531639241779767-K_Winterwear_Dk.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-right">
    <img src="https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,w_980,c_limit,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0/assets/images/2021/12/11/b96ded76-646c-4baf-9422-7727cbf2b0a11639241779745-Kurtas_Dk.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-right">
    <img src="https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,w_980,c_limit,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0/assets/images/2021/12/11/314e5e3a-0ce4-4ab3-90a3-7d02d335dbb21639241779725-Casual-Wear_Desk.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides w3-animate-right">
    <img src="https://assets.myntassets.com/f_webp,w_980,c_limit,fl_progressive,dpr_2.0/assets/images/2021/11/16/11cc5325-37c6-4490-9adb-6f09ccb2a0781637049244895-luxe-banner.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working? Please describe how it currently works, and how it should work.

Comment: slide show is not working the images are comming one below the other instead of slide

Comment: I want it to worklike slideshow but it working like normal images

Answer (score 1):

I thought of the below JS and used it with your HTML and CSS. It worked well.

However I noticed an issue which can be fixed in the CSS...

**The Issue:** When the page is refreshed and the images are all loading in, they all temporarily stack on top of each other, breaking the page's layout.

**To Fix:** In your CSS, change `display: flex;` to `display: none;` in the `.mySlides` selector. The `display: flex;` does not do anything anyway.

**After changes, CSS should look something like:**

```
.mySlides {
  display: none; /* display: flex; is now display: none; */
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  position: cover;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.dot {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.active {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
}

span {
  color: black;
  /* background-color: white; */
}
```

**As for the JS I came up with** (it uses the `setInterval` method rather than `setTimeout`). It's a bit different to yours but also a bit cleaner, see if it works for you:

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides');
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

let ID;
let slideIndex = 0;

function changeSlide(index) {
  // reset all the slides and dots to default
  // (for slides, display all none. for dots, remove all class active)
  slides.forEach(slide => slide.style.display = "none");
  dots.forEach(dot => dot.classList.remove("active"));

  // make the slide visible and the dot have a class of active
  slides[index].style.display = "block";
  dots[index].classList.add("active");
}

function startSlideShow(delay, startIndex=0) {
  // if startIndex is out of range, exit the function
  if (startIndex >= slides.length || startIndex < 0) return;

  // start slideshow at the index passed in as a parameter
  slideIndex = startIndex;

  ID = setInterval(() => {
    changeSlide(slideIndex);

    // if we are on last slide, go to first slide, otherwise go to the next slide
    if (slideIndex + 1 == slides.length) slideIndex = 0
    else slideIndex++;
  }, delay);
}

// call this function to end the slide show if necessary
function endSlideShow(goToSlide=undefined) {
  // if slide show hasn't been started, exit from function
  if (!ID) return;

  clearInterval(ID);

  // if you passed a parameter to the function (an index) then it will go to that slide
  if (goToSlide && goToSlide >= 0 && goToSlide < slides.length) {
    changeSlide(goToSlide);
    slideIndex = goToSlide;
  }
}

// begins the slide show
startSlideShow(2000);
```

With the three functions, we are able to use `startSlideShow()` which will begin the slideshow and keep changing to the next slide then eventually back to the first slide. The function uses `changeSlide(index)` to go to another slide. We also can use `endSlideShow()` to stop changing slides and optionally go to another slide after we've stopped the slideshow.

**How to use:** (pretty straightforward)

```
// to start a slide show with a delay of 2s, beginning at the first slide, use:

startSlideShow(2000);

// we don't need to pass in 0 for the startIndex because startIndex is 0 by default if you don't pass anything
```

---

```
// to start a slide show with a delay of 2s, beginning at the third slide, use:

startSlideShow(2000, 2);

// here we need to pass 2 as the second parameter or it will start the slideShow from the beginning instead
```

---

```
// end a slide show and stay on the slide it stopped at

endSlideShow();
```

---

```
// end slide show and go back to start. Next time startSlideShow() is called, slide show will start from start as well
endSlideShow(0);
```

Does this help you with what you're doing?